# How to filter by ILIKE word in gino with Postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, gino

I want to implement a suggest search in my project.
I use a gino library and wondering how to code a "like" filter in gino code?

Basically i need to write this sql statement in gino code:

```
SELECT id FROM category WHERE category.name ILIKE '%query%'
```

Cant find anything in gino docs.

Answer (score 1):

At [gino](https://python-gino.org/) main page we can see in examples:

```
users = await User.query.where(User.nickname.contains("d")).gino.all()
```

so you can try something like that:

```
category_obj = await CategiryModel.query.where(
CategiryModel.name.ilike("some_name")
).gino.first()


print(category_obj.id)
```

And you need to make CategiryModel first.

It's actually a [SQLAlchemy query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.ilike)